# Embedded for loop Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this code

```
for n in halo_param:
    for i in range(0,a):
        mask = var1['halo_id'] == n
        newtbdata = tbdata1[mask]
        hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU(newtbdata)
        hdu.writeto(('/home/ssridhar/test_roncarelli/13.8_M200_13.9/halo_{0}.fits').format(i))
```

Here `halo_param` is a chararray and `a = len(halo_param)`

```
chararray(['465000725000010', '43000145000011', '40000536000011',
   '499000523000009', '463000313000010', '470000639000011',
   '462000416000010', '499000549000008', '506000176000009']
```

What I am trying to do is, my program should take in the values of halo_param, one by one, and write out files according to the range of a (i.e **say first file should be named halo_0.fits and second halo_1.fits etc)**

**My program seems to work if I remove my second for loop** i.e it prints out the files with values of halo_param, like halo_465000725000010, halo_43000145000011 etc.

**If the second for loop is included, my program does work, but executes the same first condition for all the files**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do a loop-in-a-loop; flatten it, like

```
for i,n in enumerate(halo_param):
    mask = var1['halo_id'] == n
    newtbdata = tbdata1[mask]
    hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU(newtbdata)
    hdu.writeto(('/home/ssridhar/test_roncarelli/13.8_M200_13.9/halo_{0}.fits').format(i))
```

**Edit:** if you trace through the loop-in-a-loop, you would see that it tries to write halo_param[0] to file_0, then halo_param[1] to file_0 and file_1, ... then halo_param[8] to file_0, file_1, file_2 ... file_8. You end up with all files being copies of the last file.

Comment: This seems to work! But if possible could you explain why the loop inside the loop doesn't work??

Comment: But say if a = 10, and when we say for i in range(0,a): doesn't i take the values 0 to 9 in each step?? This is the reason I wrote the code that way.

Comment: @Srivatsan: yes, my bad: for item 0, it writes all the files; then for item 1, it writes _all_ the files _again_, destroying the work from the previous cycle; then for item 2, 3, ... 9. You end up doing the work repeatedly and ending up with only item 9's output. Flattening the loop puts item 1's data in file 1, item 2's data in file 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

fix the string format?

```
for n in halo_param:
    for i in range(0,a):
        mask = var1['halo_id'] == n
        newtbdata = tbdata1[mask]
        hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU(newtbdata)
        hdu.writeto(('/home/ssridhar/test_roncarelli/13.8_M200_13.9/halo_{0}.fits'.format(i)))
```